# Android - rotate view 180 degress only clockwise

Tags: javascript, android

I want to rotate a button only in one direction 180 degrees depending on a boolean flag. So when the flag is active the button should have a rotation of 180 and otherwise 0. This works perfectly:

```
button.animate().rotation(active ? 180 : 0).setDuration(250).start();
```

But the button is not rotating always in the same direction cause for example if the target rotation is 0 he will rotate counterclockwise.

So my question is how can I achieve the 180 rotation animation always be clockwise?

**Edit:**

So one important note is that the code could be called multiple times. So if I use rotateBy (from the answers below) it would rotate althought if it was active before. Sorry I forgot to mention that. So if the flag is active it must be `rotation % 180 == 0` otherwise `rotation % 360 == 0 or rotation == 0`

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's because the view will turn clockwise when your end degree is larger than your starting degree and counterclockwise when it's reversed. You could try getting your current rotationX value and adding 180 to it.

**EDIT:**

```
view.rate_button.animate()
    .rotationBy(view.rate_button.rotationX + rotationValue)
    .setDuration(250)
    .withStartAction { active = true }
    .withEndAction { active = false }
    .start()
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
behaviorSubject.subscribe({
    if (active && view.rate_button.rotationX == 0f) {
        // Active state is true but the button is not rotated to 180
        // degrees like we need so set the rotation value to 180 so we 
        // can still increment.
        rotateButton(180f)
    }
    else if (active && view.rate_button.rotationX == 180f) {
        // Active state is true and the button is rotated to 180
        // degrees like we need set the rotation value to -180
        // basically canceling out any rotation.
        rotateButton(-180f)
    }
    else if (!active && view.rate_button.rotationX == 0f) {
        // Active state is false and the button is rotated to 0
        // degrees like we need set the rotation value to 0
        // basically canceling out any rotation.
        rotateButton(0f)
    }
    else if (!active && view.rate_button.rotationX == 180f) {
        // Active state is false but the button is not rotated 
        // to 0 degrees like we need set the rotation value to 180
        // so we can still increment.
        rotateButton(180f)
    }
    else {}
})

private fun rotateButton(rotationValue: Float) {
    button.animate()
        .rotationBy(button.rotationX + rotationValue)
        .setDuration(250)
        .start()
}
```

For simplicity I'm still using an onclick event to fire off the `behaviorSubject.onNext` event but any action/event would work.

Comment: That would work I just forgot one thing. See in the question above.

Comment: I edited my answer above. Instead of checking your rotation degrees you could disable your button click in .withStartAction and then re-enable it when the animation is done in .withEndAction

Comment: Thanks @tgrable but the code is triggered by rxjava (BehaviourSubject) not by the user itself. I still struggling around with this problem. I think the solution must be something with a while or do while loop with a modulo check like I mention before to be sure that the rotation is correct in addition that the code could be executed multiple times. So what I meant is that the active state is changing independent of the user. In my app it's changing depending on the active slide in a viewpager.

Comment: Is the active state meant to be consistent, slide 1 = active, slide 2 = !active, slide 3 = active, etc... or is the active state independent of the viewPager?

Comment: Independent. So the user can click the button and the state of the current slide is then switched but the state for the slide is saved when the user comes back to the slide. So all slides have active = 0 in the beginning and depending on the user the states can have active = 1 and active = 0. Sorry when my explaining is not 100% clear

Comment: I updated my answer. It's not tested so it could be overkill. I'm just trying to think through the possible states active & button could be in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rotation(float) use rotationBy(float) method.

```
button.animate().rotationBy(active ? 180 : 0).setDuration(250).start();
```